# Shell script to delete lines matching a pattern and next subsequent lines following a different indentation

Tags: shell, perl, awk, sed

I have **haxproxy** configuration as below:

```
frontend bocluster
    bind <VIRTUAL IP>:8680
    mode tcp
    default_backend boservers
backend boservers
    balance roundrobin
    server boserver1 <HMASTER PRIVATE IP>:8780 check
    server boserver2 <HSECMASTER PRIVATE IP>:8780 check
```

I have to delete lines starting from the matched pattern and next subsequent lines until a line that starts in a different indentation, for eg: if I choose the pattern as `frontend bocluster`, the script has to delete this pattern and the next three lines under it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one-liner should help: (gawk)

```
awk -v p="YOURLINE" '$0~"^"p{d=1;next}d&&/^\S/{d=0}!d' file
```

- replace the `YOURLINE` by the pattern you want.
- This one-liner will remove the whole "block" of data, instead of limiting to fixed lines after the pattern. (in your example, it is three lines).

Little test:

```
kent$  cat f
foo
        a
        b
        c
        d
bar
        x
        y
        z
blah
        some
        thing
        here

kent$  awk -v p="foo" '$0~"^"p{d=1;next}d&&/^\S/{d=0}!d' f
bar
        x
        y
        z
blah
        some
        thing
        here

kent$  awk -v p="bar" '$0~"^"p{d=1;next}d&&/^\S/{d=0}!d' f
foo
        a
        b
        c
        d
blah
        some
        thing
        here
```

Comment: Thank you @Kent. I am executing your `awk` solution through our python wrapper which accepts this entire command as a string and executes it in the given cluster of nodes. `wrapper.py -n $CLUSTER_NODES -R -e "awk -v p=\"$1\" '$0 ~ \"^\"p {d=1; next} d && /^\S/ {d=0} !d' /etc/haproxy/haproxy.conf > tmp &&  mv tmp /etc/haproxy/haproxy.conf"`. I am struggling with the quotes and `$0` is expanding to the current shell script name. Basically how to debug `awk` script?

Comment: ok achieved it like this: `wrapper.py -n $CLUSTER_NODES -R -e "awk -v p=\"$1\" '\$0 ~ \"^\"p {d=1; next} d && /^\S/ {d=0} !d' /etc/haproxy/haproxy.conf > tmp && mv tmp /etc/haproxy/haproxy.conf"`

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk and regexp matching:

```
$ awk -v re='frontend bocluster' '/^\S/{f=($0~"^"re)} !f' file
backend boservers
    balance roundrobin
    server boserver1 <HMASTER PRIVATE IP>:8780 check
    server boserver2 <HSECMASTER PRIVATE IP>:8780 check
```

With any awk and regexp matching:

```
$ awk -v re='frontend bocluster' '/^[^[:space:]]/{f=($0~"^"re)} !f' file
backend boservers
    balance roundrobin
    server boserver1 <HMASTER PRIVATE IP>:8780 check
    server boserver2 <HSECMASTER PRIVATE IP>:8780 check
```

With any awk and string matching:

```
$ awk -v str='frontend bocluster' '/^[^[:space:]]/{f=(index($0,str)==1)} !f' file
backend boservers
    balance roundrobin
    server boserver1 <HMASTER PRIVATE IP>:8780 check
    server boserver2 <HSECMASTER PRIVATE IP>:8780 check
```

etc.... It just depends what awk version you have and what kind of matching you want to do - string vs regexp, whole vs partial, etc.

Comment: Thank you @Ed Morton. Any `Perl` oneliner?